# WebMethod not returning Exception data

Tags: asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api, webforms

Doing an $.Ajax() POST call to a WebMethod in a WebForms WebSite application. The calls work fine, except for when exceptions occur in the WebMethod. They are not passed down. From the WebMethod, the $.Ajax call returns an xdr.responseJson object with ExceptionType, Message, and StackTrace attributes. This is where I would expect to find the exception info but instead, no matter what the exception is on the server, ExceptionType returns "", Message is always "There was an error processing the request." and the StackTrace is "". What needs to be done for these to be populated with meaningful data from the server?

Comment: Can you show the code you've got so far? C# and javascript. Please consider creating an [mre]

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022236/c-sharp-webservice-return-error

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by changing the web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

After that change, Message, ExceptionType, and Stack trace became properly populated instead of the standard "There was an error processing the request." which gets returned for all exceptions when mode=on and is not very helpful for debugging or reporting.

Wish this setting was more granular so I could turn it off only for WebMethods.